# How to use re.split to seperate speaker and speech in transcripts?

Tags: python, regex

I am working with text transcripts and am trying to find a way to split the name of the speaker from the content of their speech. I have been trying to use re.split but so far have not had any luck.

```
dummyText1 = "bill: hello \nted: hello \nto you \nbill: goodbye \nted: goodbye \nto you"

-------------------
Original Transcript
-------------------
(L1)  bill: hello
(L2)  ted:  hello 
(L3)        to you
(L4)  bill: goodbye
(L5)  ted:  goodbye 
(L6)        to you

----------------
Desired Output
-------------------------
Speaker | Speech
-------------------------
bill    | hello
ted     | hello to you
bill    | goodbye
ted     | goodbye to you
```

My initial thinking was to use a combination of a positive lookahead for a newline + words, and the ":" symbol to mark the start of speech, but this doesn't work. I am also unsure how to group lines that will share the same speaker (i.e. so that lines 2-3 and 5-6 are processed as a single speech turn rather than individual lines).

```
splitText1 = re.split(r"(\n?=[a-z])*:", dummyText1, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

My intended output will be a list of list objects, with each nested list containing the speech ID and speech (as strings).

```
desired_output = [['bill','hello'],['ted','hello to you'],['bill','goodbye'],['ted','goodbye to you']]
```

Comment: Do you have a list of speakers?

Comment: @Pedro Rodrigues No reason at all. Are you thinking that it might be smarter to split the initial transcript into individual speech turns, and then into speaker/content pairs?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew - Unfortunately not no. Its a fairly large corpus that will be constantly changing.

Comment: Then, what is the rule to identify a speaker? Any letter word with no spaces at the start of a line until `:`? Or letter + spaces and then `:`?

Comment: Speakers are identified as any combination of letters and spaces prior to the ':' symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
dummyText1 = "bill: hello \nted: hello \nto you \nbill: goodbye \nted: goodbye \nto you"
p = r'^((?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+):(.*(?:\n(?!(?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+:).*)*)'
print( [[x.strip(),y.replace('\n','').strip()] for x,y in re.findall(p, dummyText1, re.M)])
```

Output:

```py
[['bill', 'hello'], ['ted', 'hello to you'], ['bill', 'goodbye'], ['ted', 'goodbye to you']]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5H8Zu6) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/euhpr6/1).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`, `^` also matches a position after a line break)
- `((?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+)` - Group 1: one or more letters (`[^\W\d_]`) or (`|`) horizontal whitespaces (`[^\S\r\n]`)
- `:` - a colon
- `(.*(?:\n(?!(?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+:).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!(?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+:).*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `\n(?!(?:[^\W\d_]|[^\S\r\n])+:)` - a newline  not immediately followed with 1 or more letters or horizontal whitespaces and then a `:` char
    - `.*` - the rest of the line.